# CiviMail scheduling problem due to timezone issues

Tags: civimail, timezone

i have a mailing that looks like it has been caught out due to timezone issues. The person who set it up was in NZ, but moved to Europe but didn't change their timezone. Looks like the Mailing got the scheduled time using NZ timezone, but civi sees it as happening in the future so is not sending it. Am i okay to change scheduled_date in civicrm_mailing table directly?

Answer (score 1):

I've never changed the scheduled date directly in civicrm_mailing, but it seems like a pretty harmless maneuver.

If your CMS is WordPress, I have a fork of wp-cli [here](https://github.com/PalanteJon/wp-cli-civicrm) that lets you specify the time zone in which a cron job should assume it runs.  It's specifically to handle a WordPress/Civi multisite where different sites are maintained by users in different time zones.  Each site's cron job runs in that site's local time zone.